# Changing Background Image Dynamically

Tags: react-native

I want to change my background image when i submit the city name , but don't know how to change the background image  dynamically..i have been using a ternary operator but is not giving me the desired output.(React-native noobie)

Here is my main code..

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Image, TextInput, ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import OpenWeatherMap from './Components/openweathermap';
import WeatherForecast from './Components/forecast';
import Images from './android/app/assets/images';

export default class why extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
   this.state = {forecast: null, doesShow: false};
}
textHandleChange = event => {
 let city = event.nativeEvent.text;
 OpenWeatherMap.fetchWeather(city).then(forecast =>{
   this.setState({forecast : forecast});              //Used for fetching weather data using fetchAPI
 });
}


backgroundChange = () => {
  this.setState({doesShow:true})
}



  render(){
  let content = null;
   if(this.state.forecast !== null){
     content = (

         <WeatherForecast
         main = {this.state.forecast.main}
         description = {this.state.forecast.description}
         temp = {this.state.forecast.temp}                   //For displaying the fetched Weather data
        />

     );
   }

    return(

      { {this.state.doesShow} === true ?

        <ImageBackground
       source = {Images.pic4}
       style={styles.imageDeco}>  :

       <ImageBackground
        source = {Images.pic3}
        style={styles.imageDeco}> }


       <View style= {styles.a1}>
         <View style = {styles.top}>
           <Text style={styles.a2}>Weather Forecast</Text>
         </View>
           <Text style={styles.a3}>Enter your city ID</Text>
           <TextInput
            onSubmitEditing={this.textHandleChange}
            onChangeText={this.backgroundChange}
            style={styles.a4}></TextInput>
          {content}
       </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageDeco:{
    flex:1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  },
  a1:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(47,163,218,0.2)'
  },
  a2:{
    fontSize: 30,
    color: 'rgba(128,0,0,1)',
    borderColor: '#FFF',
    borderWidth: 2,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,219,153,0.6)',
    padding: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    fontFamily: 'Lobster'
  },
  a3:{
    fontSize: 25,
    color: 'blue',
    fontFamily: 'Pacifico'
  },
  a4:{
    backgroundColor:'#ffe0bd',
    width: '30%',
    marginTop: 20,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderRadius: 50,
    fontFamily: 'Lobster',
    fontSize: 30,
  },
  top:{
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    width: '70%'
  }
})
```

[My Android Emulator..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2MCv.png)

My main aim is to change the background image from the fetched weather data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var icon = this.props.img1 ? require('image/img1.png') : require('image/img2.png');
<Image source={icon} />
```

you can change the logic here as you want, using `switch` or build the require..as you want.

And use the background img via nesting form react-native. I do this all the time. You can find details here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#background-image-via-nesting

Comment: I don't want to change the background color instead want to render a different image completely..

Comment: I updated the answer, please let me know if do you have any other question regarding this. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much , your logic worked..will try to implement this logic for changing background images based on weather data... :-)

Comment: Pls mark it as ok, so other people will know it is a good solution. Thanks